# Kernel lockdown disallows loading of an self-compiled and self-signed in-tree kernel module

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, secure-boot, kernel-module

I'm having difficulties loading a kernel module that I myself compiled and signed for Secure Boot. The module in question is `ec_sys`, located within `drivers/acpi` directory of the kernel tree.

I'm using Debian 11 stable, kernel release 5.10.0-14-amd64, kernel version 5.10.113-1.

---

**In short**, the problem is that my attempts to load the module, e.g. with:

```
sudo modprobe -f ec_sys
```

end with an error

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ec_sys': Operation not permitted

and dmesg yields the following:

> Lockdown: modprobe: unsigned module loading is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7

If I understand it correctly, lockdown should block loading **unsigned** modules into the kernel, but I **did in fact sign it**, [following Debian's official docs on the topic](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot) and it went smoothly, without any issues. I don't know why it's still being blocked.

Just for the sake of actually loading the module I even tried to disable kernel lockdown altogether via SysRq+x combination, but it seems like it's not supported in this kernel release (the 'x' command is not recognized at all).

---

For some more context, below are the steps I performed to build the module prior to enrolling a Machine Owner Key and signing the module with it.

```
# Get the source code
apt source linux 
cd linux-5.10.113

# Generate .config
make localmodconfig

# Enable ec_sys via menuconfig (or just set CONFIG_ACPI_EC_DEBUGFS=m in .config)
make menuconfig

# Prepare modules
make modules_prepare

# Build acpi modules as they're the only ones of interest to me
make modules M=drivers/acpi
```

The compilation succeeded with warnings:

> WARNING: Symbol version dump "Module.symvers" is missing. Modules may not have dependencies or modversions.
> MODPOST drivers/acpi/Module.symvers
> WARNING: modpost: Symbol info of vmlinux is missing. Unresolved symbol check will be entirely skipped.

Afterwards I copied to module to /lib/modules/$(uname -r), enrolled new MOK (as stated before) and signed the module.

---

Note: as of now, attempts to load the module without -f flag cause the following error:

> ```
> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ec_sys': Exec format
> ```

I figure this is related to the warnings mentioned above and also to the fact that `sudo modinfo ec_sys` returns

> vermagic:       5.10.113 SMP mod_unload modversions

while for any other module it returns

> vermagic:       5.10.0-14-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions

But it doesn't strike me as something to be concerned about - `apt source linux` downloaded 5.10.113 sources, because my actual kernel version is 5.10.113. It should be compatible with my kernel release (5.10.0-14), right?

---

So, just to make the questions clear:

1. Why is kernel lockdown blocking loading of a signed kernel module?
2. Is there anything that you can tell I clearly misunderstood about the whole compilation/signing/loading process and that might be affecting the result?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Each build generates a public-private keypair so the version mismatch might be at fault.

Comment: Also, what is the diff between kernel version and "release"?